# How to do logging in my app using symfony's Depenency Injection module?

Tags: symfony, logging, error-logging

I've read the current docs on Symfony integration with Monolog, but all it says is to run:

`composer require logger` which throws an error "package not found". (https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html#installation)

I'm using these components:

```
"require": {
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "~3.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "~3.0",
    "symfony/config": "~3.0",
    "symfony/console": "~3.0",
    "symfony/validator": "~3.0",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "~3.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "gedex/janrain-api": "~0.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.0",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "~3.0"
},
```

I want to do logging using dependency injection and config module.

EDIT: it is not a web application. It is a library that provides abstraction and exposes internal API, and I want to make it possible to log what is going on in the methods.

Comment: Look in the upper right hand corner of the docs page and select the 3.0 version.  If this happens to be a recent project then you probably need to upgrade your php version.

Comment: Since you are not using the framework you should start by looking at the [non-symfony monolog component](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog).  It will then be up to you to integrate it with your own app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your `composer.json`, you seem to be on Symfony 3.x still. The docs for your version are at https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/logging.html.

The `composer require logger` is a shortcut which works with Flex. Flex is default on Symfony 4, but optional for Symfony 3. If you’ve upgraded from an earlier version, I assume that you currently don’t use Flex. In this case, you can install monolog and its Symfony integration by running:

```
composer require "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0"
```

Then you must add the monolog bundle to your AppKernel:

```
    $bundles = [
        …
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        …
    ];
```

Then you can inject the `@logger` service into your own services or call it in your controllers.

Comment: Thank you, I don't use symfony/Symfony, so I'm afraid I don't have AppKernel. I'm only using Symfony components. What else should I do to get a logger?

Comment: I mean it is not a web app. It is a library that will provide services through internal API methods, but I want to make it possible to enable logging in these methods

Comment: I see. To use Monolog without Symfony, use `composer require monolog/monolog`. This will install the bare monolog library. See https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog for usage.

Comment: By the way, Symfony does not neccessarily have to be accessible though the web. I have several Symfony apps which are only accessible through CLI.